# How to write a HTML file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mjml

So I generate some HTML and I have an object that contains the HTML called html and I want to write this to a new file but right now it isn't working because and just has NaN in my saved file. This is what I have so far

```
import mjml2html from 'mjml'
import Handlebars from 'handlebars'
import fs from 'fs'

const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  <mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section background-color="#F0F0F0" padding-bottom="0">
      
      <mj-column  padding-left="70px" width="250px">
        
        <mj-text font-style="italic" font-size="22px" color="#626262">watFriends</mj-text>
        
      </mj-column>
      
      <mj-column width="170px"> 
            <mj-image width="30px" src={{logo}} />
        </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    
    <mj-section background-color="#FAFAFA">
      <mj-column width="400px">
        <mj-text font-style="italic" font-size="15px" font-family="Helvetica Neue" color="#626262">
          Dear {{firstName}},
        </mj-text>
        <mj-text color="#525252">{{message}}
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
    
`)
const context = {
  firstName: '',
  message: 'hello',
  logo: 'logo.png',
}
const mjml = template(context)
const html = mjml2html(mjml)
console.log(html)

fs.writeFile('new.html', html.toString(), { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('The file was saved!')
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mjml2html [returns an object](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/6f7a0e734027d20d4096e504665d1814d00bf450/packages/mjml-core/src/index.js#L368) like `{html: ' ...html here..', json: {}, errors: []}` and toString() of this object is string `"[Object object]"` which you are writing to a file.
Change

```
const html = mjml2html(mjml)
```

to

```
const {html} = mjml2html(mjml)
```

and all will be fine

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I needed!